# How to use static printf 3 times with LEX parser?

Tags: c, parsing, lex

I have some lex parser rules, but I want to do something like this:

- The list of the e-mails: (this is static text I want to output with printf) *john@email.com, jessica@aol.com, mike@yahoo.com* (all of them via lex rules)
- The list of websites: *google.com, yahoo.com, stackoverflow.com* (all of them via lex rules)
- The list of companies: Apple, Microsoft, Twitter (all of them via lex rules)

I don't know how can I run printf 3 times and go through the lex rules 3 times.

So it should be:

```
1 printf, 1 lex rules run
1 printf, another lex run
1 printf, another lex run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered collecting each type into its respective global array and printing them in the end whey you are done with yylex()